# Custom ngninx.conf can be applied through ConfigMap to Nginx pod but can we achieve through Secrets in Kubernetes for more security

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, configmap

I was able to accomplish the setup of ConfigMap for custom nginx.conf and mount to the Nginx pod and this works well.

My requirement is to make the credentials inside nginx.conf to be more secure and achieve through the usage of Secret.

I have tried with encoding(base 64) the nginx.conf file and applied on secret yaml file but applying deployment file throws an error.

Kindly, guide with some insights if this could be achieved with the Secrect usage as the issue lies with the secret data portion.

Secret file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
type: Opaque
metadata:
  name: nginx-secret
data:
  nginx.conf: |
      *************************************************
```

Below shows the error while running the nginx deployment file:

> error validating data: ValidationError(Deployment.spec.template.spec.volumes[0].secret): unknown field "name" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.SecretVolumeSource; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Answer (score 1):

Secrets and ConfigMaps are essentially identical. Both can be mounted as volumes in your pods; if you want to use a Secret instead of ConfigMap, replace:

```
volumes:
  - name: nginx-config
    configMap:
      name: nginx-config
```

With:

```
volumes:
  - name: nginx-config
    secret:
      secretName: nginx-secret
```

But note that this does not get you any additional security! Values in a Secret are stored in plaintext and can be read by anyone with the necessary permissions to read the secret, just like a ConfigMap.

---

A complete Deployment might look like:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: docker.io/nginx:mainline
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: nginx
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
          name: nginx-config
      volumes:
      - name: nginx-config
        secret:
          secretName: nginx-secret
```

This will mount keys from the secret (such as `default.conf`) in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`. The contents will not be base64 encoded.

Comment: Thanks @larsks for your comment, I have put the necessary secret name on my deployment file but the point is I'm trying to encode the nginx.conf portion on my secret yaml and trying to use it, which is not accepting as configmap does which is not encoded.
Also regrading security, it would be base 64 encoded when we try to read the secret.

Comment: Base64 encoding doesn't have any impact on security. It's not an encryption, it's just a different way of representing plain text. What I've posted here works just fine; the data will not be base64 encoded when it's mounted on the filesystem.

Comment: yes @larsks, I got you but for some level of security to sensitive data on nginx.conf file  going with Secrets.

Comment: Due to the visibility of sensitive data of nginx.conf file going for secrets with base 64 encoding not with simple string as on configmap. That is the reason being blocked with the Secrets.